# Global NameSpace + MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces, web-config, razor, global

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. I'm using a namespace in both my views and controllers. I decided i needed to make it a global namespace because i'm using it all over. Anyways i first added it to my main web.config. I was still getting compiler errors. So i did a search and apparently razor has its own web.config too. So i added the namespace there too. I'm still getting compiler errors. Is the main web.config used for the controller & the views web.config just used for the razor views? What am i doing wrong?

More information requested:

--main web.config

```
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="RunLogSite.POCOs"/>
  </namespaces>
```

--views web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="RunLogSite.POCOs"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Error:
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Run' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Users\Brent\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RunLog\RunLog\Controllers\RunsController.cs    27  32  RunLogSite

If i add at the following at the top of the page it is fixed:

```
using RunLogSite.POCOs;
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information.  Maybe show how your view and controller are set up regarding your namespace...maybe also show the web.config section for your namespace registration.  Lastly, as @brodie asked, what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Run' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   D:\Users\Brent\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\RunLog\RunLog\Controllers\ **RunsController.cs** 27 32
>   RunLogSite

Check the file where you are getting the error. Namespaces in web.config are only relevant to views, you still need to define all using in all cs files.

Comment: Thanks i thought a global namespace would be accessible in the controller. Guess i was wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are adding the namespace correctly, as per below ...

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Your.Custom.Namespace" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```